# LaTeX Error: File pgf-pie.sty not found

Tags: texmaker, mac, miktex2.9, pgf-pie

I run my `tex-doc` on a PC and a Mac. Unfortunately it does not compile on my mac anymore.

I get following message: ! LaTeX Error: File `pgf-pie.sty' not found.

After updating Texmaker, reinstalling packages in MikTex and searching for a solution at stackexchange, I am clueless what to try next.

I have macOS Mojave 10.14.4, Texmaker 5.0.3 for mac and MikTex 2.9.705.

Someone an idea?

P.S.: Even when no pie chart is in the document the above mentioned Error is displayed. When I delete `\usepackage{pgf-pie}` the PDF can be written.

P.P.S.:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2016.12.17)  14 APR 2019 12:27
entering extended mode
 \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**00_DOKUMENT.tex
(./00_DOKUMENT.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/03/31>
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 83 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrbook.cls
Document Class: scrbook 2016/05/10 v3.20 KOMA-Script document class (book)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrkbase.sty
Package: scrkbase 2016/05/10 v3.20 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-dependent b
asics and keyval usage)

(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrbase.sty
Package: scrbase 2016/05/10 v3.20 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-independent 
basics and keyval usage)

(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks14
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlfile.sty
Package: scrlfile 2016/05/10 v3.20 KOMA-Script package (loading files)

Package scrlfile, 2016/05/10 v3.20 KOMA-Script package (loading files)
                  Copyright (C) Markus Kohm

))) (/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/tocbasic.sty
Package: tocbasic 2016/05/10 v3.20 KOMA-Script package (handling toc-files)
\scr@dte@tocline@numberwidth=\skip41
\scr@dte@tocline@numbox=\box26
)
Package tocbasic Info: omitting babel extension for `toc'
(tocbasic)             because of feature `nobabel' available
(tocbasic)             for `toc' on input line 132.
Package tocbasic Info: omitting babel extension for `lof'
(tocbasic)             because of feature `nobabel' available
(tocbasic)             for `lof' on input line 133.
Package tocbasic Info: omitting babel extension for `lot'
(tocbasic)             because of feature `nobabel' available
(tocbasic)             for `lot' on input line 134.
Package tocbasic Info: defining new hook before heading of `' on input line 160
1.
Class scrbook Info: File `scrsize11pt.clo' used instead of
(scrbook)           file `scrsize11.clo' to setup font sizes on input line 2268
.

(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrsize11pt.clo
File: scrsize11pt.clo 2016/05/10 v3.20 KOMA-Script font size class option (11pt
)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/typearea.sty
Package: typearea 2016/05/10 v3.20 KOMA-Script package (type area)

Package typearea, 2016/05/10 v3.20 KOMA-Script package (type area)
                  Copyright (C) Frank Neukam, 1992-1994
                  Copyright (C) Markus Kohm, 1994-

\ta@bcor=\skip42
\ta@div=\count79
Package typearea Info: You've used standard option `a4paper'.
(typearea)             This is correct!
(typearea)             Internally I'm using `paper=a4'.
(typearea)             If you'd like to set the option with \KOMAoptions,
(typearea)             you'd have to use `paper=a4' there
(typearea)             instead of `a4paper', too.
\ta@hblk=\skip43
\ta@vblk=\skip44
\ta@temp=\skip45
\footheight=\skip46
Package typearea Info: These are the values describing the layout:
(typearea)             DIV  = 10
(typearea)             BCOR = 0.0pt
(typearea)             \paperwidth      = 597.50793pt
(typearea)              \textwidth      = 418.25555pt
(typearea)              DIV departure   = -6%
(typearea)              \evensidemargin = 47.2316pt
(typearea)              \oddsidemargin  = -12.5192pt
(typearea)             \paperheight     = 845.04694pt
(typearea)              \textheight     = 595.80026pt
(typearea)              \topmargin      = -25.16531pt
(typearea)              \headheight     = 17.0pt
(typearea)              \headsep        = 20.40001pt
(typearea)              \topskip        = 11.0pt
(typearea)              \footskip       = 47.6pt
(typearea)              \baselineskip   = 13.6pt
(typearea)              on input line 1528.
)
\c@part=\count80
\c@chapter=\count81
\c@section=\count82
\c@subsection=\count83
\c@subsubsection=\count84
\c@paragraph=\count85
\c@subparagraph=\count86
\scr@dte@part@maxnumwidth=\skip47
\scr@dte@chapter@maxnumwidth=\skip48
\scr@dte@section@maxnumwidth=\skip49
\scr@dte@subsection@maxnumwidth=\skip50
\scr@dte@subsubsection@maxnumwidth=\skip51
\scr@dte@paragraph@maxnumwidth=\skip52
\scr@dte@subparagraph@maxnumwidth=\skip53
LaTeX Info: Redefining \textsubscript on input line 4771.
\abovecaptionskip=\skip54
\belowcaptionskip=\skip55
\c@pti@nb@sid@b@x=\box27
\c@figure=\count87
\c@table=\count88
Class scrbook Info: Redefining `\numberline' on input line 5776.
\bibindent=\dimen102
) (/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.te
x
\pgfutil@everybye=\toks15
\pgfutil@tempdima=\dimen103
\pgfutil@tempdimb=\dimen104

(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common-li
sts.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def
\pgfutil@abb=\box28
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ms/everyshi.sty
Package: everyshi 2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.tex
Package: pgfrcs 2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.31)
))
Package: pgf 2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.15)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2014/10/28 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2016/05/09 v1.0r Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.10 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 96.

(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdftex-def/pdftex.def
File: pdftex.def 2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX

(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
\Gread@gobject=\count89
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen105
\Gin@req@width=\dimen106
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.code.tex
Package: pgfsys 2014/07/09 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.48)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
\pgfkeys@pathtoks=\toks16
\pgfkeys@temptoks=\toks17

(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered.c
ode.tex
\pgfkeys@tmptoks=\toks18
))
\pgf@x=\dimen107
\pgf@y=\dimen108
\pgf@xa=\dimen109
\pgf@ya=\dimen110
\pgf@xb=\dimen111
\pgf@yb=\dimen112
\pgf@xc=\dimen113
\pgf@yc=\dimen114
\w@pgf@writea=\write3
\r@pgf@reada=\read1
\c@pgf@counta=\count90
\c@pgf@countb=\count91
\c@pgf@countc=\count92
\c@pgf@countd=\count93
\t@pgf@toka=\toks19
\t@pgf@tokb=\toks20
\t@pgf@tokc=\toks21

(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf.cfg
File: pgf.cfg 2008/05/14  (rcs-revision 1.7)
)
Driver file for pgf: pgfsys-pdftex.def

(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-pdftex.d
ef
File: pgfsys-pdftex.def 2014/10/11  (rcs-revision 1.35)

(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-common-p
df.def
File: pgfsys-common-pdf.def 2013/10/10  (rcs-revision 1.13)
)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsyssoftpath.
code.tex
File: pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex 2013/09/09  (rcs-revision 1.9)
\pgfsyssoftpath@smallbuffer@items=\count94
\pgfsyssoftpath@bigbuffer@items=\count95
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsysprotocol.
code.tex
File: pgfsysprotocol.code.tex 2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
)) (/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
Package: xcolor 2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)

(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 225.
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1348.
Package xcolor Info: Model `hsb' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1352.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1364.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1366.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1367.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1368.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1369.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1370.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1371.
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.code.tex
Package: pgfcore 2010/04/11 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.7)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex
\pgfmath@dimen=\dimen115
\pgfmath@count=\count96
\pgfmath@box=\box29
\pgfmath@toks=\toks22
\pgfmath@stack@operand=\toks23
\pgfmath@stack@operation=\toks24
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.
tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic
.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigo
nometric.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.rando
m.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.compa
rison.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.
code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round
.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.
code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.integ
erarithmetics.code.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex
\c@pgfmathroundto@lastzeros=\count97
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepoints.co
de.tex
File: pgfcorepoints.code.tex 2013/10/07  (rcs-revision 1.27)
\pgf@picminx=\dimen116
\pgf@picmaxx=\dimen117
\pgf@picminy=\dimen118
\pgf@picmaxy=\dimen119
\pgf@pathminx=\dimen120
\pgf@pathmaxx=\dimen121
\pgf@pathminy=\dimen122
\pgf@pathmaxy=\dimen123
\pgf@xx=\dimen124
\pgf@xy=\dimen125
\pgf@yx=\dimen126
\pgf@yy=\dimen127
\pgf@zx=\dimen128
\pgf@zy=\dimen129
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathconst
ruct.code.tex
File: pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex 2013/10/07  (rcs-revision 1.29)
\pgf@path@lastx=\dimen130
\pgf@path@lasty=\dimen131
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathusage
.code.tex
File: pgfcorepathusage.code.tex 2014/11/02  (rcs-revision 1.24)
\pgf@shorten@end@additional=\dimen132
\pgf@shorten@start@additional=\dimen133
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorescopes.co
de.tex
File: pgfcorescopes.code.tex 2015/05/08  (rcs-revision 1.46)
\pgfpic=\box30
\pgf@hbox=\box31
\pgf@layerbox@main=\box32
\pgf@picture@serial@count=\count98
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoregraphicst
ate.code.tex
File: pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex 2014/11/02  (rcs-revision 1.12)
\pgflinewidth=\dimen134
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransform
ations.code.tex
File: pgfcoretransformations.code.tex 2015/08/07  (rcs-revision 1.20)
\pgf@pt@x=\dimen135
\pgf@pt@y=\dimen136
\pgf@pt@temp=\dimen137
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorequick.cod
e.tex
File: pgfcorequick.code.tex 2008/10/09  (rcs-revision 1.3)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreobjects.c
ode.tex
File: pgfcoreobjects.code.tex 2006/10/11  (rcs-revision 1.2)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathproce
ssing.code.tex
File: pgfcorepathprocessing.code.tex 2013/09/09  (rcs-revision 1.9)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorearrows.co
de.tex
File: pgfcorearrows.code.tex 2015/05/14  (rcs-revision 1.43)
\pgfarrowsep=\dimen138
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreshade.cod
e.tex
File: pgfcoreshade.code.tex 2013/07/15  (rcs-revision 1.15)
\pgf@max=\dimen139
\pgf@sys@shading@range@num=\count99
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreimage.cod
e.tex
File: pgfcoreimage.code.tex 2013/07/15  (rcs-revision 1.18)

(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreexternal.
code.tex
File: pgfcoreexternal.code.tex 2014/07/09  (rcs-revision 1.21)
\pgfexternal@startupbox=\box33
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorelayers.co
de.tex
File: pgfcorelayers.code.tex 2013/07/18  (rcs-revision 1.7)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretranspare
ncy.code.tex
File: pgfcoretransparency.code.tex 2013/09/30  (rcs-revision 1.5)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepatterns.
code.tex
File: pgfcorepatterns.code.tex 2013/11/07  (rcs-revision 1.5)
)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleshapes.cod
e.tex
File: pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex 2014/03/21  (rcs-revision 1.35)
\pgfnodeparttextbox=\box34
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleplot.code.
tex
File: pgfmoduleplot.code.tex 2015/08/03  (rcs-revision 1.13)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version
-0-65.sty
Package: pgfcomp-version-0-65 2007/07/03 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.7)
\pgf@nodesepstart=\dimen140
\pgf@nodesepend=\dimen141
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version
-1-18.sty
Package: pgfcomp-version-1-18 2007/07/23 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.1)
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgffor.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/math/pgfmath.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex
Package: pgffor 2013/12/13 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.25)

(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex)
\pgffor@iter=\dimen142
\pgffor@skip=\dimen143
\pgffor@stack=\toks25
\pgffor@toks=\toks26
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.cod
e.tex
Package: tikz 2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.151)

(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryplothan
dlers.code.tex
File: pgflibraryplothandlers.code.tex 2013/08/31 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.20)
\pgf@plot@mark@count=\count100
\pgfplotmarksize=\dimen144
)
\tikz@lastx=\dimen145
\tikz@lasty=\dimen146
\tikz@lastxsaved=\dimen147
\tikz@lastysaved=\dimen148
\tikzleveldistance=\dimen149
\tikzsiblingdistance=\dimen150
\tikz@figbox=\box35
\tikz@figbox@bg=\box36
\tikz@tempbox=\box37
\tikz@tempbox@bg=\box38
\tikztreelevel=\count101
\tikznumberofchildren=\count102
\tikznumberofcurrentchild=\count103
\tikz@fig@count=\count104

(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmodulematrix.cod
e.tex
File: pgfmodulematrix.code.tex 2013/09/17  (rcs-revision 1.8)
\pgfmatrixcurrentrow=\count105
\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn=\count106
\pgf@matrix@numberofcolumns=\count107
)
\tikz@expandcount=\count108

(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/librarie
s/tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex
File: tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex 2008/06/17 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.2)
)))

! LaTeX Error: File `pgf-pie.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name: 
! Emergency stop.
<read *> 
         
l.11 \begin
           {document}^^M
*** (cannot \read from terminal in nonstop modes)

 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 12595 strings out of 493014
 260257 string characters out of 6133350
 384103 words of memory out of 5000000
 15976 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 3940 words of font info for 15 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 64i,1n,66p,8509b,133s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Comment: Is the package installed? (it is not by default).

Comment: Check MiKTeX-console package entry then try remove and reinstall its odd that you used it in the past so in console run the bank of TASKS > Refresh …..

Comment: i have alredy reinstalled the package - even all pgf and tikz packages.

Comment: I am quite surprised that MiKTeX now offers Mac support! In any case, for a quick solution, you can download `pgf-pie.zip` from https://ctan.org/pkg/pgf-pie, extract `pgf-pie.sty` and put it in the root level of your project, alongside with your main `.tex` file... It might work...

Comment: Show the log-file of a small document with \usepackage{tikz}\usepackage{pgf-pie}.

Comment: @PauloCereda: Does not work! " ! Undefined Control sequence.\beforenumber -> \scanpercentage } - That's strange because I use the siunitx package …

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Thx - I uploaded the log file above.

Comment: It doesn't help much to update miktex when you in reality use texlive 2016. Check your path variable.

Comment: Consider that since you had TeX Live in the past (2016 version) and you think you have New MiKTeX, uninstall **either** one If you want to stick with TeX Live it would be best to reinstall as Full 2018 (HOWEVER is due to change in a couple of days to 2019 !) IF sticking with MiKTeX you may have to modify several user paths so **possibly** need to also uninstall and reinstall after TexLive is removed. Ulrike will have a better handle on the issues so heed her advice, But personally with your current mix I would wait for Full 2019 and meantime attempt if possible update pgf-pie using 2016 TLMGR

Comment: @PauloCereda: Your approach works - thank you. Nevertheless I would like to know what's my mistake. I re-installed the whole system (MacTex and Texmaker) but it does not work on my Mac. (Only when the *.sty is copied into the project folder) When I try searching for pff-pie.sty in the Tex Live Utility I can't find it! ...

Answer (score 2):

I hit the same issue on Ubuntu 18.04 with the texlive packages installed. For some reason the `texlive-pictures` package doesn't include `pgf-pie`.

This can be fixed (properly) by [downloading pgf-pie from CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgf-pie) and installing it in your local `TEXMFHOME`. You may want to verify its value before starting:

```
$ tlmgr conf texmf TEXMFHOME
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
texmf TEXMFHOME value: ~/texmf (/usr/share/texlive/texmf.cnf)
```

Install the missing pie chart macros for PGF/TikZ in `$TEXMFHOME/tex/generic`:

```
PKG_HOME=~/texmf/tex/generic
CTAN_MIRROR=https://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib
ZIP_FILE=pgf-pie.zip

mkdir -p "${PKG_HOME}" && cd "${PKG_HOME}"
wget -q ${CTAN_MIRROR}/${ZIP_FILE}
unzip ${ZIP_FILE} -x pgf-pie/demo/* && rm ${ZIP_FILE}
```

Use `kpsewhich` to verify that the file can now be found:

```
$ kpsewhich pgf-pie.sty
/home/peter/texmf/tex/generic/pgf-pie/pgf-pie.sty
```

Your LaTeX project with pie charts will build now. ([manual](https://mirror.foobar.to/CTAN/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgf-pie/pgf-pie-manual.pdf))